# Trying to reduce file size of TIFF or JPEG using R

Tags: r, image, jpeg, tiff

I am trying to reduce the file size of a TIFF or JPEG in R. This is not like the related questions that are popping up for 2 reasons. One, I am not seeing any using R which is the only language I know. Two, I have already compressed it in R, which is the typical answer for the questions posted, but I need more reduction. I feel like there must be a way to reduce quality of type image( which I am willing to do) in order to reduce file size.

```
library(jpeg)
library(tiff)
f <- system.file("ortho.img", package="jpeg")
img <- readJPEG("ortho.jpg", native = FALSE)
writeTIFF(img, "test.tif", bits.per.sample = 8L, compression = "JPEG", reduce = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please write down what you have already tried so we can assist you further. Some code is often necessary and sufficient. Till then, for jpegs you can alter quality of images using `magick`. Relevant functions are `image_read`, `image_write`.

Comment: I edited to show my code above. It is just a basic read and compress. I haven't really seen a good way to reduce it further, which is what I am after.

Comment: confused about the `system.file` line as `ortho.img` is not a file included in the jpeg package as far as I can see.

Comment: I got some advice to put that in, but it appears to be unnecessary. I took it out and i got the same output. And same issue/question.

Comment: `writeJPEG` also allows you to use the `quality` parameter so you can reduce the quality when saving a jpeg. `writeTIFF` however doesn't seem to have that option. Reading a lower quality jpeg and writing into tiff does reduce the size somewhat but I suspect there is some inefficiency there

Comment: Did you try the `magick` package as @OganM suggested?

Comment: I will have to rerun it when I get to my computer tomorrow but I did use write.jpeg and I wasn’t happy with the results. It either was not working or it didn’t compress it much at all. Also despite using this technique from current code the file is approx the same size as my original jpeg. Which I don’t get how it is possible.

Comment: So I reused the writeJPEG and it did write the jpeg succesfully, but I am not seeing a way to get it onto my server, a way to save the image.

Comment: That seems to be a different problem that requires more explanation, possibly a new question